# NextJS не работаютстили в компоненте

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

В NextJs сделал компонент с кастомным курсором, импортирую в него css молуль, но стили не применились, и className тоже отсутствует. Сам компонент я импортирую на главной странице с помощью dynamic import и { ssr: false }, чтобы был доступ к window браузера. Кто-то сталкивался? Не понятно почему отсутствуют стили

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
import { userEffec, useRef } from 'react'
import s from './Cursor.module.scss'

export default function Cursor() {
    const delay = 18;

    const dot = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const dotOutline = userRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const cursorVisible = useRef(true)
    const cursorEnlarged = useRef(false)
    
    const endX = useRef(window.innerWidth / 2);
    const endY = useRef(window.innerHeight / 2);
    const _x = useRef(0);
    const _y = useRef(0)

    const requestRef = userRef(null);
}
```

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import styles from '@/style/Home.module.scss'
const Cursor = dynamic(() => import("../components/Cursor/Cursor"), { ssr: false }):

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 0):

В Next Js все стили нужно хранить в папке styles в корневом проекте. Перемести модульный стиль в папку styles.

В импорте у тебя должно быть import s from '@/styles/Cursor.module.sсss'